# Is there a Perl wrapper for the Human interface device (HID)?

Tags: perl, cpan

Does anyone know if there a wrapper library over Human interface device library on Perl?

Comment: What is this library? You should probably provide a link or other reference.

Comment: Maybe you should get in touch with this guy: http://lists.alioth.debian.org/pipermail/libhid-discuss/2007-June/000202.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about [libhid](http://libhid.alioth.debian.org/), it's website says that you can connect it to Perl with [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/).